# How to limit a text by its size & not the length of it

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I have to solve an editor problem. I need to help building a text editor for the writers in my company. The idea was to have a fix area of the text editor that reflects the maximum size of their text. I tried to find a function to limit the area but all I could find was character length which doesnt helps since they can use bullet points and different sizes for the titles.
Here is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <script src="./ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script>
        CKEDITOR.config.resize_enabled = false;
        CKEDITOR.config.width = '50%';
        CKEDITOR.config.font-family:arial;
        CKEDITOR.config.height = '840px';
    </script>
            <textarea name="content" id="content" class="ckeditor"  maxlength="2600"></textarea>
        </body>
    </html>
```

So do you have an idea how to limit the text by the area/size of it?

Even small tips would be welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you would need to write some custom script to check if the editor is scrolling - if it is you know it is overflowing, but surely it is up to the content editor user to ensure that their content fits within the page rather than trying to change the editor to validate this.  Also surely your design can't be that brittle that having too much content breaks it

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer! Yes it should be the content editor responsible for it but in this case they are not willing to make the effort. About the design: Every section has 4 equal blocks that fit on two pages. I think we have this strict design due to the programme that send customized pdfs to all our clients base on their content and the databank we have. Thats why I need such a solution.

Comment: What happens when the user resizes their browser or views the page in a browser / device that has a different resolution to your browser and the blocks are a different size to what you have allowed?

Comment: If you are speaking of the end user as I said they only receive a pdf with the content on it so it shouldn't matter (no?) The text editor is for one of the writers in the company. For the writer if his text is too long it result on the pdf to a new block on a 3rd page and an empty  or partially empty  pace on the expected area

Comment: Periodically copy the text inside the ckeditor to another div that is off-screen.  Using the same font as you will use in the PDF, and the same size div as the area you have in the PDF, you can determine if the content of the div overflows it's defined size.  Then use that to indicate to the user that their text is too long or not.